# ASP.NET MVC deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, web-deployment

I have been deploying ASP.NET MVC 3.0 on Win 2k8 on IIS 7.5 with "Web Deploy" option.

In one of the application folder I have "CSV" folder, I have got few of the CSV template files in the folder. When I depoly the application, neither the folder gets created on the server nor any files get copied.

What is the reason and what is the fix?

Answer (score 2):

1. Move your files into the Content folder (to avoid issues with the default routes)
2. Select them in Solution Explorer
3. Right click and select Properties
4. Change the Build Action to Content

After following these steps, your files should be deployed with your application.